How to create an order with Configurable Product with Multiple options(same parent with different option)
I'am trying to create an order with Rest API in magento2 , Here i have a configurable product with id 100 and have some child product with different attribute value, here is the payload what i have created for the item
"items": [
        {
            "product_id": "100",
            "qty": 1,
            "super_attribute" : {
                        "93":"18",
                        "186":"24"
            }
        },
        {
            "product_id": "100",
            "qty": 1,
            "super_attribute" : {
                        "93":"17",
                        "186":"24"
            }
        }
   ]

here i have attribute colour with id 93 and memory with attribute id 186
When i tried to create an order its not showing the multiple option just showing only the first product data only in sales order view page

Can any one help me on this with the structure

Try once this item params :
"items": [
{
    "product_type": "configurable",
    "sku": "config-product-sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "extension_attributes":
    {
        "configurable_item_options": [
        {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": "49"
        },
        {
            "option_id": "93",
            "option_value": "45"
        }]
    }
},
{
    "product_type": "simple",
    "sku": "simple-product-sku",
    "qty": 1,
    "price": 100,
    "parent_item_id": 1
}]


Based on the RestAPI documentation, the super_attribute is not present on the possible parameters. See https://adobe-commerce.redoc.ly/2.4.7-admin/tag/orderscreate#operation/PutV1OrdersCreate
For your specific case, each configurable product option is a simple product which have it's own product_id. You should send the child product_id without any configuration options to add them into the order.
